# Can't store partial function with a Map parameter as a Map value

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a `Map` from string to a partial function. The function takes as its parameter a `Map` of the same type, but only later when the entry is retrieved. I'd like to find an entry in the map and pass the map as I apply the function, but I can't figure out how to satisfy the compiler. Here's a trivial example:

```
module M = Map.Make(String)

let () =
  let f m = M.cardinal m in
  let m = M.add "key" f M.empty in
  (M.find "key" m) m |> string_of_int |> print_endline
```

The compiler complains with this error:

```
33 |   (M.find "key" m) m |> string_of_int |> print_endline
                        ^
Error: This expression has type ('a M.t -> int) M.t
       but an expression was expected of type 'a M.t
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a M.t -> int
```

The expression type seems correct, but I'm not sure why it's expecting a `'a M.t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think of the type of `m` you'll see that it's recursive. Inside `m` are stored functions that accept values of the same type as `m`.

So, you need to allow recursive types with the `-rectypes` flag if you want this to work:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml -rectypes
# module M = Map.Make(String)
. . .
# let () =
    let f m = M.cardinal m in
    let m = M.add "key" f M.empty in
    (M.find "key" m) m |> string_of_int |> print_endline;;
1
```

Comment: Be careful about using this. There's a reason it isn't on by default.